# Find the radius in dependency of a (the side length)

Tags: geometry

[image]I really need help with this task, because it´s supposed to be in my exam...I added a picture of the geomtric figure. The task is to find out about radius r in dependency of a. So at the end it should look something like r=k*a +z+a (for example). I was trying with the Pathagoras making up these formula:

1)y²= (a-r)² + r²

2)r²=y² – (a-r)²

But it looks very complicated, like this at the end. Has anyone please got an idea how to make it easier?? and to get r just on the left side of the equation.Thank you!

all together into 2) :
r²= [(a-r)² +r²]² – (a-r)²

r²= [((a-r)²)² + 2(a-r)² +r²+(r²)²] – (a-r)²

r²= [(a-r)²(a-r)² +2(a-r)²+r²+ (r²)²] -(a-r)²

r²=[((a-r)(a-r))²+ 2(a-r)² + r²-(r²)²] -(a-r)²

r²=[(a²-2ar+r²)² + 2(a-r)²+r²+(r²)²]- (a-r)²

r²=[(a²-2ar+r²)(a²-2ar+r²)) + [2(a-r)²+r²+(r²)²]- (a-r)²]

r²=[(a²)²-2a³r+a²r² +4a²r²-2ar³-2a³r+r²a²-2ar³+(r²)²] +[ 2(a-r)²+r²+(r²)²]- (a-r)²]

r²=[(a²)²-4a³r+6a²r²-4ar³+(r²)² +2(a-r)²+r² +(r²)²)] -(a-r)²

r²=[(a²)²-4a³r+6a²r²-4ar³+(r²)² ] +2[(a-r)(a-r)]+2r² +(r²)² -[(a-r)(a-r)]

r²=[(a²)²-4a³r+6a²r²-4ar³+(r²)² ] +[2(a²-2ar+r²) +2r² +(r²)² ] -[a²-2ar+(r²)²]

r²=[(a²)²-4a³r+6a²r²-4ar³+(r²)² ]  +[a²-2ar+r²+2r²+(r²)²]

r²= (a²)² -4a³r+6a²r² -4ar²-4ar³+2(r²)² +a² -2ar+r²+2r²

[image]

Comment: Looking at picture, $r$ is not dependent of $a$.

Comment: not but should find an equation, how its compared to a. for aexample. if a was 5 centimeters, how big is r. but we dont have numbers.so it should be just an exquation. bith, radius and a are in the same square with length of sides a.

Comment: When I said not dependent I meant $r$ cannot be expressed in terms of $a$. You can make $a$ as big as you want without affecting $r$.

Comment: mh but i am sure there must be a different answer.. otherwise the professor wouldnt have said "your exam task will look like this.."

Comment: sorry I dont really know what to do either..seems hard the task

Comment: i added another picture. maybe i misunderstood something. would you mind to have a look on that picture please?

Comment: The new picture is still not enough to correct your problem. Can you tell what exactly your professor told you?

Comment: well nothing else.. unfortunatelly..i am sorry.

Comment: well i think I will upload it again tonight,when more people are online. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I think that r cannot be determined only by a. Suppose a becomes larger, r seems not necessary to change at all. I mean, your final answer must has some mistakes. If given a and y at the same time, a can be determined by Pathagoras Equation as you have written down.

Comment: its like: if a was 5 centimeters, how big is r. but we dont have numbers.so it should be just an exquation. bith, radius and a are in the same square with length of sides a. so inside that square, they are looking for an equation for the radius

Comment: i added another picture. maybe i misunderstood something. would you mind to have a look on that picture please?

Comment: r²= [(a-r)² +r²]² – (a-r)². How do you get it. It's not right.

Comment: by putting the first equation into the second equation.1)y²= (a-r)² + r²

2)r²=y² – (a-r)²

Comment: At least, the dimension is not right. In the right side you get square meter which is m^2, on the left side you get m^4

Comment: mh i dont know. do you know another way of solving? would be very great!

Comment: well i think I will upload it again tonight,when more people are online. thanks anyway!

Comment: I was wrong just now. That should be:in the equation r²= [(a-r)² +r²]² – (a-r)², suppose r=1 meter, in the left side the unit is square meter, which is m^2, in the right side you get m^4, because of [(a-r)² +r²]². From the aspect of physics law, your equation is wrong. Could you tell me what your professor exactly told you? May be you have misunderstood what he meant.